# Why doesn’t a Jasmine spy think it was called even though it returned the andReturn value?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I’m trying to debug a spy on [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) that isn’t firing, so as a sanity check, I tried

```
spyOn(this.viewModel.requests, 'submitRequest').andReturn('fooz');

var ret = this.viewModel.requests.submitRequest();
expect(ret).toEqual('foo');

expect(this.viewModel.requests.submitRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This fails with

> Expected 'fooz' to equal 'foo'.

But when I change `'fooz'` to `'foo'` in the argument to `andReturn`, the test fails with

> Expected spy on submitRequest to have been called.

The spy is returning the canned value, so why does `toHaveBeenCalled` fail?

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I know this shouldn't be the solution, but have you tried

```
var submitSpy = spyOn(this.viewModel.requests, 'submitRequest').andReturn('foo');

var ret = this.viewModel.requests.submitRequest();
expect(ret).toEqual('foo');

expect(submitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Because sometimes this works more consistently

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this test also fails: “Expected spy on submitRequest to have been called.”

Comment: @GregBacon have you tried doing a console.log(submitSpy) ? What do you get?This is really strange, what framework are you using?Backbone?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working.  I have tested it on the jasmine standalone examples:

```
it("tells the current song if the user has made it a favorite", function() {
  spyOn(song, 'persistFavoriteStatus').andReturn('foo');
  var ret = song.persistFavoriteStatus();
  expect(ret).toEqual('foo');

  expect(song.persistFavoriteStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

My gut tells me that the issue you're experiencing has to do with Jasmine's scoping of before/after calls - I've run into frustrating cases like that myself.  In the beginning of the test, I would check to make sure the environment is as you expected (ie, the spies are reset for example).